# unable to store json data in grid store in extjs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I want to display data in grid using extjs. Data from servlet is in json format.
and below is my code...problem is that i am unable to capture output from servlet to extjs.

I want to display data in grid using extjs. Data from servlet is in json format.
and below is my code...problem is that i am unable to capture output from servlet to extjs.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var myData = null;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url    : 'AccessServlet',
        method : 'GET',
        success: function (result, request) { 
            myData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
            store.loadData(myData);
        },
        failure: function ( result, request) { 
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText); 
        } 
    });


    var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        fields: [
            {name: 'name'  },
            {name: 'salary'},
            {name: 'sno'   },
        ]
    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store  : store,
        height : 350,
        width  : 400
        columns: [
            {
                header: 'SNO', 
                width : 100
            },
            {
                header: 'NAME', 
                width : 100 
            },
            {
                header: 'SALARY', 
                width : 100 
            },
        ],
    });

    grid.render('example-grid');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Ajax` to load store, use `proxy` config and appropriate `reader`. 
Is your data array of arrays? Maybe your json has wrong format